# Unable to locate dropdownlist in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

So i have a dropdownlist that appears when my gridview is in edit mode. The problem is that when i press the update button, I get a null reference error. This is because for some reason the update event claims that the dropdownlist does not exist within the gridview. The same can be said when i look at the markup. However, when i run the page and press the edit button my dropdownlist comes up with no problems. Can anyone tell me why this is the case?

This is what i have so far for the codebehind with the update event:

```
        protected void GridViewHolder_Updating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) 
    {

        int machineid1;
        string machineid;
        string machineTypeid;
        string machineModelid;

        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridViewHolder.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        machineid = ((Label)(row.Cells[0].Controls[1])).Text;
        machineid1 = Convert.ToInt32(machineid); 
        machineTypeid = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[3].FindControl("MachineTypeDropDown"))).SelectedValue;
        machineModelid = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[4].Controls[1])).SelectedValue;



        //inputsService.UpdateMachineTypes(machineid, machineTypeid);
        //inputsService.UpdateMachineModels(machineid, machineModelid);

    }
```

below you will find the mark up and the .ascx gridview markup:

viewsource:

```
<th scope="col">Site Name</th><th scope="col">Machine Name</th><th scope="col">Machine Type</th><th scope="col">Machine Model</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>

                        </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:Transparent;">

                            <td>SACRAMENTO</td><td>DC04</td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl02_MachineTypeLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl02_MachineModelLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl$GridViewHolder','Edit$0')" /></td>

                        </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:Transparent;">

                            <td>SACRAMENTO</td><td>DC1</td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl03_MachineTypeLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl03_MachineModelLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl$GridViewHolder','Edit$1')" /></td>

                        </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:Transparent;">

                            <td>SACRAMENTO</td><td>MPS01</td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl04_MachineTypeLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl04_MachineModelLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl$GridViewHolder','Edit$2')" /></td>

                        </tr><tr align="center" style="background-color:Transparent;">

                            <td>SACRAMENTO</td><td>MSE01</td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl05_MachineTypeLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td>

                        <span id="AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl_GridViewHolder_ctl05_MachineModelLabel">empty</span>                            

                    </td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('AssignMachineTypesAndModels_userControl$GridViewHolder','Edit$3')" /></td>
```

gridview markup:

```
 <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" 
                                   SortExpression="ID" 
                                   Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'
                                   Visible="false">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SiteName" 
                                HeaderText="Site Name" 
                                SortExpression="SiteName"
                                ReadOnly="true" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" 
                                HeaderText="Machine Name" 
                                ReadOnly="true" 
                                SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Type" 
                                   SortExpression="MachineType">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="MachineTypeLabel" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("MachineType") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="MachineTypeDropDown" 
                                          runat="server" 
                                          AppendDataBoundItems="True"                                                
                                          Height="21px" 
                                          Width="217px" 
                                          DataSourceID="GetMachineType" 
                                          DataTextField="Name" 
                                          DataValueField="ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                                          Text="Select a Machine Type." 
                                          Value="NULL">
                            </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Machine Model" SortExpression="MachineModel">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="MachineModelLabel" 
                                   runat="server" 
                                   Text='<%# Bind("MachineModel") %>'>
                        </asp:Label>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="MachineModelDropDown" 
                                          runat="server" 
                                          AppendDataBoundItems="True"                                                
                                          Height="21px" Width="217px" 
                                          DataSourceID="GetMachineModel" 
                                          DataTextField="Name" 
                                          DataValueField="ID">
                            <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" 
                                          Text="Select a Machine Model." 
                                          Value="NULL">
                            </asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" 
                                  ShowEditButton="True"
                                  CausesValidation="false" >
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                               Wrap="True" />
                </asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why is your GridView in the session ? `GridView gv = (GridView)Session["MachineTable"];`

Comment: I use that in when trying to debug this problem in hopes to see what my code was coming into my code, and breakdown the location in the controls to try and find where the dropdownlist was.

Answer (score 3):

As Etch says you might need to search through the entire control hierarchy. However Etch's approach is flimsy. The FindControl mechanism in a control is a bit weak currently as it only checks that controls children directly - not the hierarchy. Below is an implementation that will check through it all looking for the control with the ID that you want.

```
/// <summary>
/// Similar to Control.FindControl, but recurses through child controls.
/// </summary>
public static T FindControl<T>(Control startingControl, string id) where T : Control
{        
    T found = startingControl.FindControl(id) as T; 

    if (found == null)
    {
        found = FindChildControl<T>(startingControl, id);
    }

    return found;     
}

 /// <summary>     
/// Similar to Control.FindControl, but recurses through child controls.
/// Assumes that startingControl is NOT the control you are searching for.
/// </summary>
public static T FindChildControl<T>(Control startingControl, string id) where T : Control
{
    T found = null;

    foreach (Control activeControl in startingControl.Controls)
    {
        found = activeControl as T;

        if (found == null || (string.Compare(id, found.ID, true) != 0))
        {
            found = FindChildControl<T>(activeControl, id);
        }

        if (found != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

So you would call this with your gridview container as the first param, and the ID of the child control you are looking for. E.g if you implemented these methods into a class called ControlHelper (there are better ways ... )

```
DropDownList theList = ControlHelper.FindControl<DropDownList>(grdViewParentInstance, "MachineTypeDropDown");

if(theList != null) {
    theList.Selected... ;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the use of generic (why asp.net FindControl doesn't implement that yet, i can't understand... ?). Code is so much more readable without all the castings.

Comment: @rangitatanz So how would i go about implementing the call to the findcontrol method, to be more specific, i'm not sure i fully understand what i would put in for the parameters when calling it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked all the controls in the controls collection?

I remember having to do somthing like this:

```
 machineModelid = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0].Controls[1])).SelectedValue;
```

The control could be nested within another control?  I would also check your html markup with a "view source" and see if anything looks odd or out of place.

I would also suggest posting some markup. So we know a little more of what we are dealing with.